# Checking if <video> tag can display a media and handling an error in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, video, components

My goal is to check if HTML5 video element can display a video from given src. I build my application using Angular. Below is how my html component's template and controller look.

Every model passed to component's controller has it own path and name. When path points to valid mp4/webm/ogg file - it is displayed perfectly. But I want to check if a file from given path is supported. in case of error I'd show to user a dialog saying `{{vm.name + 'cannot be displayed'}}`

There are plenty of methods of HTML Audio/Video DOM Reference from w3 but i simply don't know how to use them. Moreover I noticed that I can't use inline js in template html file of a component.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

So? How to check if a file can be shown in video tag?

`video-preview.html`

```
<header class="dialog-header">
    <span>{{vm.name}}</span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon close-btn icon-close" ng-click="vm.closeDialog()"></button>
</header>
<div class="dialog-content">
    <video class="video-preview-dialog" id="myVideo" autoplay src="{{vm.path}}" controls></video>
</div>
```

`video-preview-dialog.controller.js`

```
(function () {
'use strict';
 angular
    .module('videoApp')
    .controller('VideoPreviewDialogController', VideoPreviewDialogController);

  /** @ngInject */
  function VideoPreviewDialogController(model, VideoDialogInstance) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.path = model.path;
    vm.name = model.name;
    vm.closeDialog = closeDialog;

    function closeDialog() {
      PreviewDialogInstance.cancel();
    }

  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to pass a function with "&" sign from a controller to directive, and invoke it when error occurs.
1. Link  tag in dirctive
2. Set to player eventListener("error", passedFunction())

That was it